Trouble Setting Up "E-POST für Salesforce" App in Sales Cloud
I’m facing issues starting with the "E-POST für Salesforce" app in Salesforce Sales Cloud. Has anyone used this package or knows how to obtain credentials for it?
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I installed the package for the E-POST für Salesforce app from the AppExchange in Sales Cloud.
I registered for the Business API from Deutsche Post AG and received a contract approving API usage.
I reached out to Deutsche Post AG for credentials to configure the package in Sales Cloud, but they redirected me to the software developer, saying activation depends on the package creator.
The problem: The package provider listed on AppExchange as "YOUR SL GmbH" no longer exists. Their phone contact routes me to Salesforce, but Salesforce hasn’t confirmed ownership of the "E-POST für Salesforce" software either.

Without the credentials or guidance, I’m unable to proceed. Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to navigate this situation?
Thank you in advance!

You should contact the vendor directly. Apparently Salesforce bought the biz back in 2016 (and I note that their app exchange listing points to an invalid web site). I suggest you raise a support case with Salesforce, if you don't have an account manager.

Yeah, I already created a support case at Salesforce about a month ago, stated the same what you've said, but Salesforce didn't helped to far. All agent communication ends with "I am going to check it internally with my team and will circle back to you" and the same agent never showed up again with any solution... passing the case from one to another. It's a nightmare, they have no clue apparently

Sorry to hear you are getting blocked. Unfortunately, this isn't the right forum for this type of question. I recommend looking to use a different app for whatever you are doing.

Based on your experience, it's clear the app has been orphaned and nobody wants to own it.  There is a microscopic chance that if you can find a former employee who owns the rights to the app source code, they might make a deal with you.  As Phil says, you'll just have to find a different solution.
